# Repeated sequencing based on columns value

Tags: r, indexing, sequencing

Im really new to R so Im sorry if I dont make total sense.

I have a DF with data collected in several different areas, called STAND. I need to create a sequence for my data running from 1:3, but is has to restart the sequence when it comes to a new STAND number.

Here is some dummy data

```
    STAND   TREE_SPECIES    DIAMETER
1   101737  Pine             276
2   101737  Spruce           98
3   101737  Spruce       104
4   101737  Leaf         53
5   155897  Spruce       82
6   155897  Spruce       61
7   155897  Leaf         97
8   155897  Spruce       89
9   155897  Spruce       75
10  202568  Spruce       46
11  202568  Spruce       56
12  202568  Pine         204
13  202568  Spruce       132
14  202568  Spruce       93
```

I want it to look like this:

```
    STAND   TREE_SPECIES    DIAMETER     SEQ
1   101737  Pine             276          1
2   101737  Spruce           98           2
3   101737  Spruce       104          3
4   101737  Leaf         53           1
5   155897  Spruce       82           1
6   155897  Spruce       61           2
7   155897  Leaf         97           3
8   155897  Spruce       89           1
9   155897  Spruce       75           2
10  202568  Spruce       46           1
11  202568  Spruce       56           2
12  202568  Pine         204          3
13  202568  Spruce       132          1
14  202568  Spruce       93           2
```

If it is any help I have a total of 7416 Rows in my DF divided on 90 STANDS.

So far I've tried:

```
  myDF$SEQ <- seq(1:3)
```

But that only lists 1:3 over the whole df.

Really greatful for your help!

Comment: Hi and Welcome to stackoverflow! As you are new on SO, please take some time to read [about Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [how to ask](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are much more likely to receive an answer if you provide a [minimal, reproducible data set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and show us your attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df$SEQ <- ave(x = df$STAND, df$STAND, FUN = function(y) rep(1:3, length.out = length(y)))
```

Or shorter, but with the same result, if you can live with warning messages due to the recycling of 1:3 sequences along the lengths of each STAND - lengths which are not necessarily multiples of the length of 1:3:

```
df$SEQ2 <- ave(df$STAND, df$STAND, FUN = function(y) 1:3)
```

The result:

```
df
#     STAND TREE_SPECIES DIAMETER SEQ SEQ2
# 1  101737         Pine      276   1    1
# 2  101737       Spruce       98   2    2
# 3  101737       Spruce      104   3    3
# 4  101737         Leaf       53   1    1
# 5  155897       Spruce       82   1    1
# 6  155897       Spruce       61   2    2
# 7  155897         Leaf       97   3    3
# 8  155897       Spruce       89   1    1
# 9  155897       Spruce       75   2    2
# 10 202568       Spruce       46   1    1
# 11 202568       Spruce       56   2    2
# 12 202568         Pine      204   3    3
# 13 202568       Spruce      132   1    1
# 14 202568       Spruce       93   2    2
```

`ave` splits the `x` vector (here: STAND), into pieces defined by the levels of the next (unnamed) argument (here: STAND). The default function `FUN` that is applied to each of the pieces in `ave` is `mean`. Here we change that function to an 'anonymous function', `function(y)`, that we define as `rep(1:3, length.out = length(y))`. The 'y' corresponds to each of the pieces. You could replace 'y' with any name of choice (e.g. `function(chunk) rep(1:3, length.out = length(chunk))`. You will see that quite often people uses `function(x)`, but I didn't want to use 'x' as the name of each piece here because 'x' is also used as the argument in `ave` for the entire vector. For each piece, `rep`licate the values 1:3 to the desired length (`length.out`), i.e. the length of each piece: `length(y)`